# Is it possible to only show particles that collided and stick to an object?

Tags: particles, collision

(version 2.80)

I would like to only show particles that have collided (and stick) to some object. I do not want to show the particles that are still travelling to an object.

I am thinking this can be done if I only show the dead particles, that died in the collision with the object. And to not show all the travelling alive particles. Therefore I ask whether it is possible to only show the dead particles. And if so, how?

This has to be done in an animation, accumulating showing particles sticking to the object during the animation.

A different solution to obtain this result is also greatly appreciated.

So I want the following animation, without showing the particles that fly around and did not collide...
https://ibb.co/CpyvW1H

still frame:
[image]

Comment: If you only want particles on such object why not simply add a particle system directly on it?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos it is important for the visualization that I simulate the emitting of the particles from a central point. So I don't know before hand on what surface the particle will collide, this is found during the animation.

Comment: You add proper explanation of all the constraints and illustrations of the desired effect and what you have so far to your question

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos did what you asked, hope it is clear now

Comment: Dynamic Paint seems like what you're describing.